# Modify the road calculation algorithm in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps

I would like to know if it is possible to change the way the itinerary calculation algorithm works in the Google Maps API (or Bing Maps). Basically, I'd like to add options, like for example "shortest route" or "avoid highways and national roads".

I haven't found anything in the API that might manage the road's cost, so I think it's not possible but maybe someone's got an idea of a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to modify the pathfinder algorithm beyond the `avoidHighways` and `avoidTolls` options. See here for documentation: 
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsRequest

Another method would be to specify `provideRouteAlternatives` and figure out which of these routes is best according to your own heuristic.

Comment: Well, yes but what I want is get other types of alternative road calculation.
Say, for example "Route with only left-turns" or things like that.

Comment: Sorry - then no, there's no way for end users to modify the path finder algorithm

Comment: Maybe you could edit your answer to add that there is no way for end-user to change the path finder algorithm behind the "avoidHighway" and "avoidTolls" option, like that I can mark your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: Thanks, now let's hope that they will change this to allow a bit more flexibility.